# MySQL query to select some data from a second table in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically, I have a function that exports data to a csv format for excel... I'm trying to have a single query to select all of the sales record within the selected time period, but I need the first column that is queried to come from another table. The current query I have is as follows:

```
$select = "SELECT `record_date` AS 'Sale Date',
                  `record_order_number` AS 'Order #',
                  `record_activity_number` AS 'Activity #',
                  `record_total_diy_revenue` AS 'Revenue $'
             FROM st_entered_records 
            WHERE `record_user_id` = '$this->user_id' AND 
                  `record_date` BETWEEN '$this->start_date' AND '$this->end_date' ";
```

Before

```
`record_date` AS 'Sale Date'
```

I need it to run a second select to get the users first and last name in format:

```
"LastName, FirstName"
 (user_last_name)", "(user_first_name) from a second table (st_users) 
 where `user_id` = '$this->user_id'
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Sounds like you want a JOIN rather than another query.

Comment: You need an `inner join` or maybe `left join` if its not a guarentee to be a row in other table.

Comment: Or you can double select your query, something like:
SELECT name, headofstate, population
  FROM Country
  WHERE population=(SELECT MAX(population) FROM Country);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a join example of one:

```
    SELECT t2.lastName,t2.firstName,
           t1.record_date AS 'Sale Date',
           t1.record_order_number AS 'Order #',
           t1.record_activity_numbe AS 'Activity #',
           t1.record_total_diy_revenue AS 'Revenue $' 

    FROM st_entered_records1 t1

    INNER JOIN stusers t2 ON t1.record_user_id=t2.userid

    WHERE t1.userid = $this->user_id AND
    t1.record_date BETWEEN $this->start_date AND $this->end_date
```

Be sure you match the table names and field names I'm sure you already know this :)

EDIT:  `Stongly advise you do not use MYSQL_*`

Reason:

`This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.`

Comment: I'd just like to point out that nowhere in the question the OP stated that he was using `mysql_*`, for all I know he could be using `$pdo->query()`, `mysqli_query()`, or `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Look at the question tag it says `mysql` not `sql` not `pdo` not `mysqli`

Comment: Also i am not missing AS any where `tablename t1` is perfectly valid thanks.

Comment: The question tag `mysql` indicates that OP is using a MySQL database, it doesn't necessarily mean that he is using the `mysql_*` PHP functions.

Comment: `mysql` !== `mysqli` plus there is no harm in me mentioning the warning just encase ;) Future users will now know also.

Comment: I didn't say they were identical, I just said that nowhere in the question do we see any `mysql_*` functions being used.

Comment: From my experience its better to take the question literally rather than assumption - you would be surprised with some things people ask! SO has a tag for `mysqli` and `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
    `st_entered_records`.`record_date` AS 'Sale Date',
    `st_entered_records`.`record_order_number` AS 'Order #',
    `st_entered_records`.`record_activity_number` AS 'Activity #',
    `st_entered_records`.`record_total_diy_revenue` AS 'Revenue $',
    `st_users`.`user_last_name` AS 'LastName',
    `st_users`.`user_first_name` AS 'FirstName',
FROM `st_entered_records`
INNER JOIN `st_users` ON `st_entered_records`.`record_user_id` = `st_users`.`user_id`
WHERE
    `record_user_id` = :uid AND
    `record_date` BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate;
```

By the way I've replaced the variables with named parameters. I strongly recommend the use of prepared statements, but if you insist on using concatenated queries (whether with mysql, mysqli, or PDO), remember to escape the variables!